# Filter by type in Google AutocompleteService

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to filter away `establishments` in my autocomplete service.

I have tried

```
var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService;
var request = {
  "input": "Nørregade",
  "componentRestrictions": { "country": "dk" },
  "types": ["(cities)", "(regions)", "geocode"]
};
service.getPlacePredictions(request, function(predictions, status) {
  console.log(status) # => INVALID_REQUEST
});
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/gdk0j9eg/1/)

Following this link (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompletionRequest) it seems that the autocomplete service does indeed take these types.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3), you are only allowed to use a single type or type collection:

> You may restrict results from a Place Autocomplete request to be of a certain type by passing a types parameter. The parameter specifies a type or a type collection, as listed in the supported types below. If nothing is specified, all types are returned. **In general only a single type is allowed.** The exception is that you can safely mix the geocode and establishment types, but note that this will have the same effect as specifying no types.

Comment: So I can only do the opposite of what I want? Is there any way I can filter out the `establishment` type?